# insert line break at the end of paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div id="insert" contenteditable="true">KATATAY
puyus katatachkan
warmikunapa
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

jquery
all that remains is to put line breaks

```
$('#insert').keyup(function(){
    $('#result').html('<span>'+$('#insert').text().split(/\s/).join('</span><span>'));
    $('#result').find( "span" ).addClass('over');
});
```

I want to make this way.
**the result must be so**

```
<div id="result">
    <span class="over">KATATAY</span><br>
    <span class="over">puyus</span><span class="over">katatachkan</span><br>
    <span class="over">warmikunapa</span><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `#insert` supposed to be a `contentEditable` element?

Comment: looks like it's just not ***insert line-break at the end of paragraph***, the actual requirement is much more than that, please edit the question title.

Comment: Uh, `join('</span><br /><span>')` maybe ?

Comment: Couldn't all this be avoided by just using actual `<p>` tags in the HTML in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var over = 'over';
$('#result').html(function() {
    return $('#insert').text().trim().split(/\n/).map(function(elem) {
       var ret =  '<span class="over">' 
                  + elem.split(/\s+/).join("</span><span class="+over+">") 
              + '</span></br>';
       return ret;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('#result').html(function() {
    return $('#insert').text().trim().split(/\n/).map(function(el) {
       return '<span class="over">' 
                  + el.split(/\s+/).join("</span><span class='over'>") 
              + '</span></br>';
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ss57Z/

Comment: but not working in `contentEditable` which is what I need. *please if you would be so kind*